# wrong args for environment subassignment when trying to set values for a hashmap in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use HashMaps in R and get the following error message:

```
wrong args for environment subassignment
```

Here is what I did:

```
lvls <- union(levels(data$p1), union(levels(data$p2),levels(data2$p3)))
map <- new.env(hash=T, parent=emptyenv())
map[[lvls]] <- 1:length(lvls)
Error in map[[lvls]] <- 1:length(lvls) : 
  wrong args for environment subassignment
```

typeof(lvls): character

strangely `map[["example-value of lvls"]] <- 1` works fine
but `map[[lvls]] <- 1` not

What I'm ultimately trying to do is convert the characters of p1, p2 and p3 into factors while the same character should be the same factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you are trying to use an environment here, but you can not assign multiple elements at a time with the `[[` operator. It would probably better to use `assign()` and just `mapply()` over your values

```
Map(assign, lvls, seq_along(lvls), MoreArgs=list(envir=map))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this works fine. As I mentioned I want to ultimately convert p1, p2 and p3 into factors. 

I had the following in mind:
data$p1 = map[[data$p1]]
which doesn't work either as map won't take a vector

I estimate that it has to be something like  Map(get, data$p1, MoreArgs=list(envir=vector))

Comment: I'm now using 
     groups <- unique(c(levels(data$p1), levels(data$p2), levels(data$p3)))
    data$p1 = factor(data$p1 levels=groups),
    data$p2 = factor(data$p2, levels=groups),
    data$p3 = factor(data$p3, levels=groups)